# Migrate Gitlab Database from v6.3 to v7.5?

Tags: linux, gitlab

What way is the best way to migrate all projects, issues, users, snippets and everything else from an old gitlab installation to a new one?

Our old machine is a bitnami VM with GitLab 6.3.0 - The commands from the backup [guide](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/raketasks/backup_restore.md) are not working:

- `sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create` > command `gitlab-rake` not found
- `sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:backup:create RAILS_ENV=production` returns `Could not locate Gemfile`

So is it even possible to transfer the data from v6 to v7 with this? - And how?

The new machine is running on Ubuntu 14.04 with Gitlab 7.5.3 (Omnibus, .deb installation) (fresh installed, works and nothing changed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to this link: https://community.bitnami.com/t/cannot-run-gitlab-backup-in-6-6-4/22936 you obviously running the command in the wrong directory.

The correct path, where your Gemfile is located is `/opt/bitnami/apps/gitlab/htdocs`.

This should create a backup in the `/opt/bitnami/apps/gitlab/htdocs/tmp/backups` by default (if not changed in the Gitlab config file)

This file should contain all necessary information for migrating to the new server.

Comment: for migrating Gitlab to a Gitlab-Omnibus install there's a good [walkthrough](http://theterminallife.com/migrating-gitlab-to-gitlab-omnibus/)

Comment: Thanks, again. The previous way don't work because the versions are different. And updating v6.3 to current would be maybe one ore more questions on serverfault - if know what I mean :)